# Canvas exceeds the grid layout

Tags: html, css, canvas, grid, particles.js

I am trying to create a grid layout that contains 3 content columns and an `.overlay` div that contains [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) canvas.

Here is the codepen of what I'm struggling with: https://codepen.io/radzak/pen/MVQVPQ

I'd like the grid to always be 100% of the screen, so I set this

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

The issue is that after I extend the window size and then decrease it back again the canvas keeps occupying the space it used to (instead of 100vw x 100vh). I've also noticed that the canvas `width` and `height` doesn't correspond to the actual size it occupies.

I have no idea what is happening, any help on how to set this layout up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `position: absolute` on the `canvas` to remove it from the document flow.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm, at least for now :D